# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am having a problem at a Java program. Exception in thread "main"

> exception in thread main java.lang.nullpointerexception at VenueHireSystem.main (VenueHireSystem.java:27)

is the error that I'm getting. I could really use some help, since i am stuck hours on this spot...

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class VenueHireSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner sc = null;
          try
          {
              sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));  
          }
          catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
/*        finally
          {
              if (sc != null) sc.close();
          }
*/       
          
          Manager VenueManager = new Manager();
          
          String info;
          String key;
          
          while (sc.hasNextLine() && sc.hasNext()){
              key = sc.next();
              info = sc.nextLine();
              if (key.equals("Venue")){
                  VenueManager.addVenueAndRoom(info);
              } else if (key.equals("Request")){
                  VenueManager.RequestBooking(info);
              } else if (key.equals("Change")){
                  VenueManager.ChangeBooking(info);
              } else if (key.equals("Cancel")){
                  VenueManager.CancelBooking(info);
              } else if (key.equals("Print")){
                  VenueManager.PrintBooking(info);
              }
          }
          
          sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you catch a `FileNotFoundException`, the `Scanner` will be `null` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Never silently swallow an exception.

Comment: Really appreciate your quick replies but I'm totally new to Java. I know the error is in the exception handling but I don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks for your quick reply, what am I supposed to catch then if I didn't catch the FileNotFoundException?

Comment: If the file cannot be found, just print an error message and exit the program.